# Frame transformations in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have a vector $k^{\alpha}$ in a frame *A*

A second frame *B* has a 4-velocity w.r.t frame *A* of $u^{\mu}$.

How would I determine the original vector in frame *B*, $k^{\beta}$, for a general (i.e. not necessarily Minkowski) spacetime?

Reading the literature seems to suggest using a projection operator

$$ P^{\alpha \beta} = g^{\alpha \beta}  + u^{\alpha} u^{\beta}$$

such that,

$$ k^{\beta} = P^{\alpha \beta} k_{\alpha}$$

but I do not understand why this should be true.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is it you mean under "frame" in this context?

Comment: Well, just the set of 4 orthonormal vectors. Out of interest, is there another meaning?

Comment: Well, we usually consider *fields*, and in case of *fields*, there is a difference between general (anholonomic) frames and coordinate (holonomic) frames. What you asked is entirily pointwise, though, but nontheless if I start fiddling with $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$-matrices for general frame transformations I would probably confuse you if you expect a coordinate-based answer.